# Wordpress - get_results() - How to know if failed or empty?

Tags: database, select, wordpress

I use the Wordpress function $wpdb->get_results()

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results

**It says:**

*"If no matching rows are found, or if there is a database error, the return value will be an empty array."*

Then how can I know if the query failed OR if it's empty?

Answer (score 22):

Use

```
$results=$wpdb->get_results($yoursql);
if (count($results)> 0){
    //do here

}
```

But if you want to know if query failed

```
$wpdb -> show_errors ();
$wpdb -> get_results ($wpdb -> prepare($sql));
$wpdb -> print_error ();
```

Comment: Then I get the last error, not if the last query has an error or not. The last error could have been 10 queries ago.

Answer (score 8):

Bit late to the party here but I'm just looking for the same thing. I've had a browse through the `wp-db.php` code on version 4.4.2.

On line 1422, inside the method `flush()` there's a bit of code which resets the `last_error` property:

```
$this->last_error  = '';
```

This `flush()` method is called in the `query()` method on line 1693:

```
$this->flush();
```

The `get_results()` method calls `query()` on line 2322:

```
if ( $query ) {
    $this->query( $query );
} else {
    return null;
}
```

With this we can be pretty sure that more or less every time `get_results()` (Or `get_row()` too for that matter) is called, `query()` and `flush()` are both called, which ensures that `last_error` is set to the empty string before the query is executed.

So assuming the query runs (If it doesn't, `null` is returned - if the query is empty for example), `last_error` should contain an error message if the query was to fail for some reason.

Since `last_error` is `flush()`ed/reset each time, it should only contain an error for the last query that was run, rather than the last error for any query that had been run previously. With this in mind it should be safe to rely on `last_error` to determine whether something went wrong with the query.

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
if (is_null($results) || !empty($wpdb->last_error)) {
    // Query was empty or a database error occurred
} else {
    // Query succeeded. $results could be an empty array here
}
```

Not the most intuitive in my opinion, but it seems to be sufficient.

Personally, I've written my own class around `wpdb` for my own benefit. This is my `getResults()` method.

```
public function getResults($query, $bindings = [])
{
    // Prepare the statement (My prepare method inspects $query and just returns it if there's no bindings, otherwise it uses $wpdb->prepare()        
    $prepared = $this->prepare($query, $bindings);

    // Execute the statement
    $rows = $this->db->get_results($prepared, ARRAY_A);

    // If an array was returned and no errors occurred, return the result set
    if (is_array($rows) && empty($this->db->last_error)) {
        return $rows;
    }

    // On failure, return false
    return false;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Wpdb->get_results function from wordpress returns the result if successful otherwise it will return null. There can be many reasons if a query get failed.Refer in-depth article on debugging get_results() returning [empty results here](https://geekswordpress.blogspot.com/2021/07/wordpress-getresults.html)

Although you can use functions like `wpdb->show_error()` to check what was the last error after executing the sql query. sometimes this error returns empty
then try to use `wpdb->last_query` to check the final query that get formed.